# How to send/receive data with complicated data structure via pipe?

Tags: c++, directshow, pipe

```
HRESULT GrabberCB :: SampleCB ( double SampleTime , IMediaSample * pSample )   {      

How to send the pSample content via pipe?

}
```

I know how to send/receive `string` by `WriteFile/ReadFile` after reading this sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365592%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

But how to send a `pSample` over?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your data before sending over any transport and at the other end you need to deserialize the data to convert it back.  There are lots and lots of ways to do it depending on simple / complex your data is.

You could roll your own or use some sort of framework like [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) or COM.  There is no right answer, it all depends on what you are trying to do, how complex your data is and what sort of performance you require.

Comment: Can you illustrate how `COM` can be used to do the job?

Comment: You just use the COM Framework to create server components that you use in the client.  So the client just creates the server com class and calls it's methods.  All the call / argument passing is doing all the marshaling for you.  If you want the server component to notify the client of events, then you would use COM Connection Points (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/connection.aspx) which are just callbacks.  So you have to think of the solution in a different way than you would if using some sort of transportation pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to send it on a pipe?  It would be a lot easier if the pipe reader were a COM object instead and you just let the COM framework take care of everything.  That being said, you can marshal a COM object into a stream (even out-of-process) with CoMarshalInterface; perhaps you could then send that stream across the pipe and reconstitute it with CoUnmarshalInterface.